# Add-Member in ForEach-Object Loop with Current Property

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am trying to add a new member with a variable value in a new array ($dataset_datasources) while looping through objects from the source array.

ForEach-Object loops through the source array ($report_datasets) objects and uses a property in a REST Get call.

The new array stores all the responses correctly, but I need to add the looping objects' property ($PSItem.Id) in the index each loop.

````
```
$report_datasets = @($reports | ForEach-Object {Get-PowerBIDataset -Id $PSItem.DatasetId -WorkspaceId c44b3318-7e99-4537-a78d-cafd8cf0d1a8})
$dataset_datasources = @($report_datasets | ForEach-Object {Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url "datasets/$($PSItem.Id)/datasources" -Method Get} | ConvertFrom-Json).value
```
````

Current output

```
datasourceType connectionDetails       datasourceId    gatewayId
-------------- -----------------       ------------    ---------
File           @{path=c:\users\3.xlsx} 8fc513f8        215671c5
File           @{path=c:\users\2.xlsx} 3495ef3e        215671c5
File           @{path=c:\users\1.xlsx} 6dffe553        215671c5
```

Desired output

```
datasourceType connectionDetails       datasourceId    gatewayId    datasourceId
-------------- -----------------       ------------    ---------    --------------
File           @{path=c:\users\3.xlsx} 8fc513f8        215671c5     value of $PSItem.Id..
File           @{path=c:\users\2.xlsx} 3495ef3e        215671c5     value of $PSItem.Id..
File           @{path=c:\users\1.xlsx} 6dffe553        215671c5     value of $PSItem.Id..
```

I have tried using Add-Member in the loop but encountered an error stating the member already exists.. what am I missing/need to change?

Comment: You cant have objects with the same property names, chose a different name for your new property

Comment: If I choose new names then the array columns increase, which is not the objective here.

Comment: Please add the code you're currently using to attach the new property to your objects